# How can I translate with webkit-transform enough so that

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, webkit

I am using webkit-transform: scale(zoomFactor,zoomFactor) in css to zoom the contents of an iframe.  When I zoom it to the proper size to fit inside the iframe, the positioning of the elements is offset like this:
[image: diagram]
I cannot figure out how to find the x and y I would need to offset it to get it so that the contents of the iframe appear to be in the same corner as before it was scaled.  The amount the contents are offset depend on how large or small the scalefactor is.  Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: -webkit-transform-origin:0px 0px

Comment: @cocco Wow that worked!  So simple thank you so much, I would mark this as answer if you made it one!

Comment: here is the answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using transforms you can set the transform origin.

In your case you want to scale to the top left.

so the origin should not be default (center) but at 0px left and 0px top.

```
-webkit-transform-origin:0px 0px;
```

Comment: This was such a simple fix, but it completely solved my problem.  Thanks for the answer!